# Creating a jar of a project built with maven?

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven project in which (under src/main/java) i have many packages and (but there is only one central pom.xml) Each package provides a different functionality than the other.
So now i need to create a jar file of one particular package.If it was a normal java package(i.e not built with maven) ,I would have simply extracted that package(using Export in eclipse and then selecting java->jar option) but i cant figure out a way to do this with maven. 
I also checked out Apache Maven Assembly Plugin but i couldn't figure out how to fit that plugin in my scenario.
I am new at maven so kindly help me out.
Thanks

Comment: You should be more precise with your wording. A "package" is a means to organise your classes and has itself no functionality. If you want different jars, split your sources into separate Maven modules. Rule of thump: one module/project per artifact.

Comment: Gyro speaks the truth. In other words: if you want to use Maven, use Maven as it is designed. You'll find that the way Maven wants you to work ultimately is a lot more flexible and streamlined.

Comment: I was handed over this project and i agree that maven should be used as it is designed so i have split the source and then how should i create the jar from it.I have used  Apache Maven Assembly Plugin and did the necessary changes in pom and then selected  run as-> "maven-install" via eclipse which created a jar  in the target folder of my project now i want to know is the process of running this jar is different form a normal jar(also please let me know if i haven't created the jar correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven jar plugin:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/service/*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: That creates one jar. How would you use the jar plugin to create say 10 jars for 10 packages?

Comment: To generate several jars you must use Maven assembly plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: Then that would be a fitting answer to this question, not what you currently present. Because what is asked is exactly what I describe.

Comment: You didn't say you want create "one jar for each package", you said "So now i need to create a jar file of one particular package", so I meant only one jar.

Answer (score 0):

Best in Maven is to create a multi module build for each part you would like to have a separate module which creates it's own jar. This will make it easy to separate functionality as well according tests.